# Margin rendering bug in IE9, using ExtJS 3.4

Tags: css, extjs

I'm using ExtJS 3.4 in IE9, and having an issue with drag & drop ordering in a TreePanel.

When you apply a margin to the html element using css, for some reason the margin overlaps the first few elements in the TreePanel, stopping you from dragging and re-ordering them.  The higher you set the margin, the more elements become unusable.

I guess what I'm looking for is an IE9-only css fix that'll allow me to change the behaviour in that browser only.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue in 3.4?

Comment: Recently upgraded to ExtJS 3.4 and noticed our **EditorGridPanel** drag & drop ordering no longer works in Internet Explorer 9, or Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: _Update_ to above on the ExtJS [Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?138116-Extjs-3.4-Grid-to-grid-drag-and-drop-when-floating-true) I found some more common issues with the drag & drop and Internet Explorer 9. I was able to add 'position:relative;' from 'position:absolute;' to the DIV element that contained the **EditorGridPanel**. That fixed the problem and drag and drop works again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, was caused by any of the tree control's containing elements being floated.

Comment: be clear with you ans and Provide examples  
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question